# why does sql comparison ignore case

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

I'm doing some sqli challenges (overthewire.org, the natas web application challenges) and during one of the sqli challenges I encountered the following problem.

when I do compare substr(password,1,1)="a" it will ignore the case. So for example

```
Select * from users where username="user" and substr(password,1,1)='a'
```

will be true and so will be

```
Select * from users where username="user" and substr(password,1,1)='A'
```

If I use

```
`Select * from users where username="user" and ascii(substr(password,1,1))=ascii('a')`
```

instead everything works fine.

Does someone have information why it is implemented that way? is this the default mysql behaviour?
Best

Comment: thanks, the later is basically the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

In a nutshell you can specify a collation that the database will use and most default to a case insensitive collation, hence it ignores case when comparing text.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-general.html